# Converting video to HTML5 ogg / ogv and mpg4

Tags: video, html, mpeg

Does anyone know about any software that can convert video (avi, flv, whatever) to HTML5 supported ogg/ogv and mpeg4 formats?

I tried a few but I couldn't find anything that actually works.

Comment: `mpeg4` is not a very modern web format. Currently only supported by Chrome (?) and soon to be deprecated there. Check out [webm/VP8](http://www.webmproject.org/)

Answer (score 49):

The Miro video converter does a beautiful job and is drag-n-drop. 
http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/

BTW it's FREE and also very good for mobile device encoding.

Comment: On Os X does a great job as well!

Comment: NOD32 Detects this as an potential unwanted software? includes toolbars or something...

Comment: No toolbars that i know of; also this answer was posted like 9 months ago, they may have added them. Like with most software installers, people should read before they click "next" or "ok".

Comment: As a follow up to this, it asks if you would like to install AVG toolbar, but can opt out

Comment: I miss the option of batch converting to all the html5 video formats at once, also drag & drop doesn't work on windows 8

Comment: Damn that was nice feature on Win8; I can't verify because I'm mostly on Ubuntu now.

Comment: Damn useful post tho, even though it was closed :(  o.O  . Miro worked great for me.

Comment: This would be great if you could edit the bitrate etc when converting video. Unfortunately there are no options/settings available for this. Using VLC instead.

Comment: Watch out, MP4 converted with miro does not play on IE10 etc. for mp4 I recommend handbrake https://handbrake.fr/ (also free and even opensource)

Comment: That link gives a 404

Comment: @JaydenLawson sometimes after 7 ish years links go away... Goggle can save the day http://www.getmiro.com/

Comment: Thanks! That will be useful to others also

Answer (score 18):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) should be able to do this.

Comment: Best option, free & effective

Comment: Best answer ever! Easy to use and free, use the wiki if you don't know how: https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo_New/

Answer (score 2):

For OGG on Windows: [Theoraconverter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/theoraconverter/)

Answer (score 0):

MS Expression Encoder can do mp4/h.264. not sure about ogg though.

Comment: You need the pro version $ 200,-